# Вызов деструктора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Пишу вектор. При перегрузке операции + возникают проблемы.

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator +(Vector<T>& v)
{
    Vector<T>* v1 = new Vector<T>(_size + v._size,"temp_v1");
    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++)
    {
        v1->at(i) = ptr[i];
    }
    for(int i=_size;i<v1->_size;i++)
    {
        v1->at(i)=v.at(i-_size);
    }

    return *v1;
}
```

При `Vector<T>* v1 = new Vector<T>(_size + v._size,"temp_v1");`, в моём понимании, просто выделяется память под n элементов типа `Vector<T>`, но после `return *v1;` для него вызывается деструктор.

```
int main()
{
    Vector<int> v(0,"v"),v1(0,"v1");  
    v.push_back(0);  
    v1.push_back(1);  

    Vector<int> v2;  
    v2 = v+v1;  

    std::cout<<v2<<std::endl;
}
```

Соответственно, насколько я понял, в `v2` ссылается на 2 элемента очищенного блока памяти и, при вызове деструктора для `v2`, программа падает, ссылаясь на двойную очистку памяти.

Поясните пожалуйста, почему это происходит и как это поправить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не надо создавать объект в куче. Заводите обычную локальную переменную:

```
Vector<T> v1(_size + v._size, "temp_v1");
// необходимые манипуляции
return v1;
```

При это, конечно, должен быть реализован минимум необходимых функций. Т.е. следует ознакомиться с ["правилом трех"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Тогда, скорее всего, все Ваши ошибки двойного удаления уйдут.

P.S. В современном C++ "правило трех" расширяется до "правила пяти", а в качестве альтернативы может быть заменено на "правило ноля".
Более подробно можно ознакомиться [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/221033/).

Comment: «правило трёх» устарело, сейчас это «правило пяти или нуля»

Comment: @ixSci согласен. Но не уверен, что новичков нужно сразу грузить про перемещение. Тем более, когда нет метки `c++11`.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в 16 году C++(метки) нужно понимать как C++14, если не указано обратное.

Comment: @ixSci я бы с радостью согласился, но к сожалению, учебных материалов по современному c++ на русском не так много. И новички типа ТС обучаются еще по литературе c++03 версии языка в 90% случаев, даже если их текущий компилятор поддерживает более новый стандарт.

Comment: может тогда укажите в скобках, что для современного C++ можно ещё другое правило использовать? Я погуглил, вроде на том же хабре есть описание «правила нуля». Это может и не будет полезно автору, но будет полезно другим, кто попадёт на эту страницу

Answer (score 5):

Смотрите, вы создали `Vector` в динамической памяти. Он себе тихонько висит. Вы возвращаете `*v` - ссылку на него. При возвращении из функции вызывается копирующее присваивание (кстати, именно копирующее, потому что вы возвращаете lvalue-ссылку, а не rvalue). Все. Удалять ваш динамический объект некому - с чего бы? Указатель как переменная с локальным временем хранения будет удален (соответственно, имеет потерянный объект в памяти и ее утечку), а объект в динамической памяти - нет.

Как вам посоветовали, делайте возвращаемый вектор локальной переменной - еще и возможность оптимизации RVO получается.

Двойного освобождения **в приведенном коде** я не вижу, но что и как у вас делается в остальной реализации - неизвестно. Тут у вас вижу только утечку памяти. неплохо, чтобы вы предоставили [минимальный воспроизводящий проблему пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

И еще - не перемешивайте вы так безбожно индексы от трех объектов, еще и с очень похожими именами - глаза сломаешь, продираясь :)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Проблему решил, она как раз заключалась в "правиле трех", которое упомянул предыдущий оратор.